# Multisite installation on an existing single installation

Tags: multisite, installation, directory

How to create a blog in a sibling directory of an already installed WordPress  directory?

The domain is `example.com` and there is an existing installation in `blog` directory and the root directory at `example.com/` is free. Is it possible to create a blog at `example.com/anotherblog/` through multisite instead of `example.com/blog/anotherblog/`?

On a new installation at the root this can be achieved by simply installing WordPress at the root and having two multisite blogs in two directories. However, that is total of 3 blogs(including the one at the root). Can the same be achieved without the 3rd blog and keep the root free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this can't be done.

I think WP multisite can only control blogs that are underneath it - which is why you'd have to install WP at the root.

I was once looking to do the same thing, and unfortunately all my research pointed to "no" being the answer.

Comment: If you wanted, you can install at root, have two blogs in subdirectories and put your custom `index.whatever` welcome file at the root. However, this is not neat and it's like overriding the blog at the root.

Comment: my above comment doesn't work; I did try it out. Also, I'm accepting this as the answer because I'm not able to find any other answer anywhere!